# Trying to access Settings.Settings from second Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, settings, config

### Problem Summary

I have two projects (Console Application and Settings Console). I want "Console Application" to access "Settings Console's" Settings.settings file and use that data in the program.

### What I've Done

I've already set the Settings.Settings Access Modifier to "Public", and Have set the Scope of each setting to "User"

### Settings Console Output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Settings_Console
{
     class Program
     {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
            //Show Stored Settings
            Console.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.Name + "" + Properties.Settings.Default.Number);
            String name, number;
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            number = Console.ReadLine();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Name = name;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Number = number;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            //Show Settings Changed into
            Console.WriteLine(Properites.Settings.Default.Name + "" + Properties.Settings.Default.Number);

           }
      }
}
```

### Settings Console Output:

```
Amanda 9568675309
Sergio
9568254235
Sergio 9568254235
Press any key to continue . . .
```

## Console Application Project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System_Console;

namespace Console_Application
{
      class Program
      {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                  Console.WriteLine(Settings_Console.Properties.Settings.Default.Name + "" + Settings_Console.Properties.Settings.Default.Number);

            }
       }
}
```

## Console Application Output:

```
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Debug the console application project and check each property in the chain, i.e. Properties, Settings, Default, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!